# Equivalent of viewWillAppear() in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I'm rebuilding an iOS app using Flutter and the flow is as followed: 
Everytime the user lands on the homepage, the user data is reloaded from the backend to check if anything has changed.

The way I achieve this in Swift / iOS is by using the viewDidLoad() function.

My Flutter code is like this:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  User user = User();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _fetchData(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        color: RColor.COLOR_main,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 7,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20),
              child: Container(
                child: Text("This is the homepage"),
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  Future _fetchData(BuildContext context) async {
    _fetchUserAPI(context);
  }

  Future _fetchUserAPI(BuildContext context) async {
    try {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var accessToken = prefs.getString("access_token");
      var url = RConstants.API_BASE_URL + "/v1/users/self";
      Response response = await Dio()
          .get(url, options: Options(headers: {"Authorization": accessToken}));
      setState(() {
        user = User.fromJson(response.data);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      Alert(
              context: context,
              title: "Something Went Wrong",
              desc: "Something went wrong while fetching your user data",
              type: AlertType.error)
          .show();
    }
  }
}
```

void initState() however, doesn't get triggered each time the user lands on the homepage. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: build method is executed every time you open the screen

Comment: @diegoveloper but it is not the ONLY time. That will get triggered every time the state changes

Comment: @Rutger, were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: @Jan completely changed the app's architecture. moved onto using BLoC pattern. i recommend looking into that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it really depends on what exactly you mean by "Everytime the user lands on the homepage".

If user navigates from the `HomePage` to some other view via `Navigator.push` and then goes back via `Navigator.pop` then the `HomePage`'s state remain the same and of course the `initState` method does not trigger.

If you want to get notified on the `HomePage` if the route above it in the navigator gets popped then you need to use [this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Route/didPopNext.html) method, override it and then inside it you will be able to call the `_fetchData()` and update the homepage's state.

One more thing: when you have some async call like `_fetchData()` it is a wrong pattern to just invoke it inside the `initState()` or any other framework methods. Because it will be invoked and the `build()` method of your state will almost always be invoked immediately before the result of async call will come back. The correct way to handle such situations is to use the [FutureBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) widget.

If "Everytime the user lands on the homepage" means something else, like e.g. the app was in the background and gets brought foreground or when there is support for push notifications implemented and users click on the notification and the app is opened - such cases also can be handled but that is a broader topic.

Answer (score 3):

`RouteAware` can help.

1. define `final RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>> routeObserver = RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>>();` in main.dart.
2. set `navigatorObservers: [ routeObserver ],` in MaterialApp function.
3. mixin `RouteAware` in your page that need achieve `viewWillAppear` feature.
4. override `didChangeDependencies` and `didPopNext` methods and subscribe this page to `routeObserver`.

For example:

main.dart

```
final RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>> routeObserver = RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>>();
void main() {
    runApp(MaterialApp(
        home: HomePage(),
        navigatorObservers: [ routeObserver ],
    ));
}
```

home_page.dart

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with RouteAware {
    @override
    void didChangeDependencies() {
        super.didChangeDependencies();
        routeObserver.subscribe(this, ModalRoute.of(context)!);
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
        routeObserver.unsubscribe(this);
        super.dispose();
    }

    @override
    void didPopNext() {
        super.didPopNext();
        debugPrint("viewWillAppear");
    }
}
```

Comment: The following _TypeError was thrown building IconTheme(color: Color(0xdd000000)):
type 'List<NavigatorObserver>' is not a subtype of type 'List<RouteObserver<ModalRoute<void>>>' of 'other'

Comment: using CupertinoApp and same error as @SwiftiSwift

Comment: @swifthing updated the answer to fix it

Comment: How can I use it in other widgets?